# Concatenating cell arrays of different sizes

Tags: matlab

It would be appreciated if you could help me concatenate two cell arrays that have different sizes. For example, consider the cell arrays:

```
a={'p' 'e' 't' 'k'; 2 3 4 6; 3 5 9 8; 5 4 1 0; 8 9 6 5};
b={'a' 'v'; 1 2; 3 4; 0 5; 6 8};
```

Array `b` could have a different size, depending on the iteration result. I want to combine these cell arrays, so that I end up with

```
c={'p' 'e' 't' 'k';2 3 4 6; 3 5 9 8; 5 4 1 0; ...
    8 9 6 5;'a' 'v' NaN NaN;1 2 NaN NaN; 3 4 NaN NaN;0 5 NaN NaN; 6 8 NaN NaN};
```

How can I do this, when the sizes of `a` and `b` are different each time I run my code?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to concatenate a 34*5 cell-array with a 17*3 cell-array? That won't work, unless you "pad" one of the arrays so that the size of at least one dimension aggres. For instance, you could 0-pad the 17*3 cell array so that you have a 17*5 cell array, and then concatenate. Alternatively, you can create a nested cell array. Both are described on the [Mathworks page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html).

Comment: the a and b are inputs and c is desired output:                                      >> b={'a' 'v' ;1  2; 3 4;0 5; 6 8}; 
>> a={'p' 'e' 't' 'k';2 3 4 6; 3 5 9 8; 5 4 1 0;8 9 6 5};
>> c={'p' 'e' 't' 'k';2 3 4 6; 3 5 9 8; 5 4 1 0;8 9 6 5;'a' 'v' NaN NaN;1  2 NaN NaN; 3 4 NaN NaN;0 5 NaN NaN; 6 8 NaN NaN};

Comment: I proposed a substantial edit to your question - please check if the question is still what you intended to ask. I have a feeling that English is not your native language (which is OK!), but please try your best to ask clear questions. Formatting code in the question body (four spaces) or in comments (backticks, ```) helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to "pad" the smaller cell array, then you can concatenate both cell arrays [with standard methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html). In the comment to your question you indicated that you want to pad the matrix with `NaN`. This is how you could do it, assuming that the width of array `b` is smaller or equal to the width of array `a`:

```
a={'p' 'e' 't' 'k';2 3 4 6; 3 5 9 8; 5 4 1 0;8 9 6 5};
b={'a' 'v' ;1 2; 3 4;0 5; 6 8};

sa = size(a);
sb = size(b);    
columns_to_pad = sa(2) - sb(2);  

padding = num2cell(NaN*ones(sb(1), columns_to_pad));    
b_padded = [b, padding];    
c = [a; b_padded];
```